# Detect changes in TextField in Flutter

Tags: flutter, textfield

I have created a function which return 4 textfields in column and I have called that function from 4 different containers, now how do I know from which container textfields are being changed because all the textfields are common to different containers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can we see some code to better understand the problem?

Answer (score 3):

in general you can handle the changes in Textfield in two way

1- Using `onChanged()` callback

```
TextField(
  onChanged: (text) {
    print('First text field: $text');
  },
),
```

2- Using a `TextEditingController`

you create a controller

```
 final myController = TextEditingController();
```

Connect the TextEditingController to a text field.

```
TextField(
  controller: myController,
  ),
```

Create a function to print the latest value.

```
void _printLatestValue() {
  print('Second text field: ${myController.text}');
 }
```

Listen to the controller for changes.

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  // Start listening to changes.
  myController.addListener(_printLatestValue);
}
```

in your case you can pass controllers to your function and listen to it

Comment: is there a way to know something actually changed when using addListener? cuz whenever I move the caret the listening function is triggered. I can use a variable to store the last value and compare to current value, but seems like there should be a better way

Answer (score 0):

What about using [keys](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/Key-class.html). You can choose unique keys for each of the different textfields(maybe you can generate keys when you programmatically generate the textfields). Alternatively, you can assign unique keys to the containers as well.

Answer (score 0):

flutter textfield has onChanged property, you can do inside onChanged

Comment: how to know from which container textfield is being changed, because textfield widget is common to multiple container.